# Windows Common Control Bug?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, common-controls

Recently I have faced with very strange behavior of the Windows "Button" control having BS_MULTILINE style, which looks like bug in Windows. To reproduce it, make the following:

(1) Create new project with Visual Studio 2012 Project Wizard; choose "MFC application";
(2) On "Application Type" page choose "Dialog based" + "MFC standard";
(3) On "Advanced Features" page keep only "Common Control Manifest";
(4) In the generated "Resource.h" file add the line `#define IDC_LONG_TEXT    103`;
(5) In the generated <project-name>.rc file replace "TODO" static text inside the main dialog definition by the lines:

```
LTEXT       "BUG IN WINDOWS COMMON CONTROLS.\nButton containing image and text does not work with BS_MULTILINE style.",IDC_STATIC,10,10,250,20
PUSHBUTTON  "Very Long Text.",IDC_LONG_TEXT,10,35,250,45,BS_LEFT | BS_TOP | BS_MULTILINE | BS_FLAT
```

(6) In the generated <project-name>Dlg.cpp file, in the `OnInitDialog()` handler, add the following code after "TODO" comment line:

```
CString strOrigText, strLongText;
CWnd* pButton = GetDlgItem(IDC_LONG_TEXT);
pButton->GetWindowText(strOrigText);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    strLongText += strOrigText;
pButton->SetWindowText(strLongText);
pButton->SendMessage(BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)m_hIcon);
```

(7) Build and run the program. You will see that the button text is drawn in the upper-right corner of the button. If you comment the last line in the above code, the text will be drawn correctly.

Does anybody faced with the same problem? Is it really a bug? If so, how it can be submitted to Microsoft?

Comment: It's been a while since I have had to do anything with rc files and dialogs...I'm wondering, though, if the text is being justified to the right of the image? And, if that's the case, maybe you can make a bigger button or try using the BS_TEXT flag to change the behavior.

Comment: Well, I can confirm that I see the same behaviour using VS2012 and VS2013 and I can't see anything wrong with the combination of styles you've used. If you use `BS_RIGHT` instead of `BS_LEFT`, you get the same problem on the other side. You can [submit a bug via MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) if there isn't one already.

Comment: Can you provide details about the platform (Windows version, version of the common controls, x86/x64)? Have you produced a test case without MFC to eliminate the framework as a potential source?

Comment: @IInspectable, the bug has no relation to MFC; originally it appeared in a COM component written with ATL. I created the MFC example only to be sure that it is not my fault.

Comment: @IInspectable, Sorry, other data: Windows7/x64, Common-Controls DLL version 6 (previous versions do not support buttons with both text and image).